# How can I redirect URL's with numbers using by htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I need redircet a lot of pages on my site.
all those page url is:

```
/index.php?act=download&id=9&mirror=0
/index.php?act=download&id=9&mirror=1
/index.php?act=download&id=9&mirror=2
/index.php?act=download&id=10&mirror=0
/index.php?act=download&id=10&mirror=1
```

Etc.
I need to write in my htaccess file this code:

```
Redirect 301 /index.php?act=download&id=9&mirror=0 http://mydomain.com
Redirect 301 /index.php?act=download&id=9&mirror=1 http://mydomain.com
Redirect 301 /index.php?act=download&id=9&mirror=2 http://mydomain.com
Redirect 301 /index.php?act=download&id=10&mirror=0 http://mydomain.com
Redirect 301 /index.php?act=download&id=10&mirror=1 http://mydomain.com
Redirect 301 /index.php?act=download&id=10&mirror=2 http://mydomain.com
```

but I have a lot more..
how can I redirect all of this:

```
/index.phpact=download&id=ANY-NUMBER&mirror=ANY-NUMBER
```

to my main page? (http://mydomain.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant match query string using `Redirect` directive. Use `mod_rewrite` instead:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^act=download&id=[0-9]+&mirror=[0-9]+
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://mydomain.com? [L,R=301,NC]
```